# Central limit theorem backwards

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem

Does the fact that some quantity in nature is normally distributed necessarily imply that the quantity can be meaningfully expressed as a sum of smaller iid components (e.g. IQ is a sum of small genetic effects)?

In other words, can the normal "exist on it's own" so to speak, without being a limit of a sum?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean, but any continuous random variable can be converted to a standard normal by means of the probability integral transform, and vice-versa. So, for any reasonable interpretation of your question, the answer should be no.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. As far as the classical CLT goes the sum of multiple iid random variables approaches normality as long as the number of these variables approaches infinity.

My question is: if we observe a quantity e.g. female height which distribution very closely fits normal curve can we conclude that the above quantity may be decomposed into a (sufficiently large) set of independent random parameters (say, lengths of various bones in the body)?

Comment: A Normal distribution is infinitely divisible so this answers the question.

Comment: @Xi'an I still think the question is unclear in the sense that it I'm not sure how to convert the original question into a firm mathematical statement. OP seems to want to say something along the lines of "if I observe a normal distribution in nature, can I always express it meaningfully as a sum of smaller iid components, e.g., IQ is a sum of small genetic effects". You seem to interpret it as "given a normally distributed $X$, can I find a set of iid increments such that the sum is equal in distribution to $X$" which is a sharper question but not clear that it captures what OP wants.

Comment: @guy: I completely agree. My comment was more tongue-in-cheek to point out that the question is meaningless from a probabilistic point of view.

Comment: Gentlemen, what you say makes perfect sense mathematically wise. Of course if one takes a standard normal it can be "constructed" in infinite number of ways. What I'm trying to figure out is whether the normal can "exist on it's own" so to speak, without being a limit of a sum, if it makes sense (which it probably doesn't).

Comment: Reformulated the question considering all the comments. I understand that the question doesn't make much sense mathematically but still think it's worth being asked in terms of applications of probability.

Comment: This question is related to Benford's law (on the log scale)

Comment: Given the rewording of the question (which is still not really a sharp question) consider that calling `rnorm(1)` in `R` gives a normally distributed random variable using the Box-Muller transformation (I consider generating by computer to be a natural phenomenon, but it is easy to do a physically experiment as well). It does not seem to me that this involves any kind of summing of small components (although there may be an extremely pedantic way to characterize it as such), i.e., the normal in the Box-Muller transform does not arise from the CLT. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @guy, thank you but not really I'm afraid. As far as I can see the Box-Muller comes from the same family of integral transforms that can convert uniform to anything but just in a bit more convoluted trigonometric form of representing the exponent. My question is (let's give it another shot) if a quantity (say, in physics) previously known as atomic is discovered to be normally distributed, can we conclude right away that it's nature cannot be considered atomic anymore? So it seems to be more of a question about binomial rather than normal.

Comment: which makes a lot less sense mathematically since we can construct an n-sided die that can be biased specifically to produce pretty much any distribution. Works similar to the integral transforms I guess. So the answer to the initial question is no, it seems, as you stated in the very beginning. Thank you @guy.